# Global maximum of multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a function of two variables that is bounded and positive, and goes to zero as either of the two variables goes to plus/ minus infinity.  The function is not concave.  All critical points are local maxima, but I do not know if there is one or more critical point.  If there are no saddle points, when can I conclude that there is a single local maximum (and hence global maximum).

Comment: If the function is strictly concave for instance, a critical point will be for sure a global maximum. In any case I don't understand why you mention the Karush Kuhn Tucker conditions since they apply to constrained optimization problems (inequality constrains).

Comment: Thank you.  The function is not strictly concave.  My particular problem involved KKT conditions, but you are correct that they are not necessary for the answer.